# Удалить на баше много файлов, зная только длинну их имён

Tags: bash

В папке есть очень много файлов без префиксов и постфиксов. Файлы такого типа:

```
6854e37da3ad67a1bfa38a43bc3dea03
4e440d92372ad5a91f30dbff249f39d8
3eb560e2483c8959522da6209569405a
8a985608766a14b1a2dc91ce9928181c
pf35edf64f80276db31109da6da0cb78
g1b89cb11e3225ffada1cb5946902ec7
```

Удалять группами по маске какой-то вроде `rm 6*` — нельзя, т.к. в папке есть еще нужные другие файлы которые могут таким образом удалиться.
Единственное что пока приходит на ум — удалять по длине, т.к. они все имеют одинаковое количество символов в названии.
Если есть еще какие-то более умные варианты — буду благодарен.

Answer (score 7):

есть такое понятие как маска. И что бы указать один символ имени, нужно указать знак вопроса. Поэтому, быстрое решение будет такое

```
rm ????????????????????????????????
```

конечно, перед удалением лучше выполнить

```
ls ????????????????????????????????
```

Comment: справедливости ради, хочу заметить, что  `rm` не работает с большим количествоим файлов по маске) тогда через find удалять) а так собственно ваш вариант - вполне рабочий, интересно, есть ли более изящный вариант.

Comment: Не работает на древних версиях баша.

Answer (score 5):

помимо [предложенного варианта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673960/178576) с маской, состоящей из 32 символов `?`, могу предложить следующее:

очень похоже, что имена файлов содержат только шестнадцатиричные цифры — `0123456789abcdef` (а символы `p` и `g` «затесались» в пример случайно). отобрать файлы с такими именами можно, например, так:

```
$ ls | grep '^[0-9a-f]\{32\}$' | less
```

в конце `less` — это для удобства просмотра, чтобы убедиться, что не попали в выборку файлы, которые не следует удалять.

если «всё верно», реально удалить файлы можно, заменив в команде `less` на `xargs rm`.

---

конечно, можно добавить и символы `pg`:

```
$ ls | grep '^[0-9a-fpg]\{32\}$' | less
```

или даже с уточнением: `p` или `g` могут быть только первым символом в имени (тогда надо 32 заменить на 31, чтобы сохранялась общая длина имени):

```
$ ls | grep '^[pg][0-9a-f]\{31\}$' | less
```

Answer (score 3):

Удалять через ls плохая практика.

```
~$ find /path/to/dir -type f -regex ".{32}" -exec rm -rf {} \;

~$ find /path/to/dir -type f -regex ".{32}" -print0 | xargs -P$(nproc) -0 -n1 rm
```

".{32}" - имена с любыми символами в количестве 32 шт

2й вариант распараллелит в потоки - nproc это количество прцессоров в системе, что ускорит удаление если файлов больше 100кк
.

Правда, как заметили в коментарии, скорости удаления это не прибавит.

Значительный прирост идет только от использовния *xargs* вместо ключа *-exec*

Comment: Вероятно, только ключ должен быть не `-name`, а что-то вроде `-regexp`. Да и скорость файловых операций вряд ли зависит от количества ядер процессора.

Comment: Вы правы, поправил.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что у find можно параметре опции `-exec` указать модификатор `+` вместо `;`. Таким образом `find ... -exec rm -f {} +` почти эквивалентно `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`.

Comment: @mymedia спасибо за наводку, приведу примеры с таймингом.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно: (+ в питоне можно задавать очень сложные условия без проблем)

```
 for filename in $(find *.* | python3 -c "while True: line = input(); print(line) if len(line) == LEN_STRING else None");do rm ${filename}; done
```