# Как вывести файлы названием которых содержит меньше пяти символов скажем? unix

Tags: ubuntu, unix

Как вывести файлы название которых содержит меньше пяти символов скажем?

Comment: В одной папке или во всей системе?

Comment: В одной папке,или во всей системе,не важно,мне необходимо принцип понять,у find атрибута я такого не нашел вроде как...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/673952/178576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /your_path -type f -print| awk -F/ ' length($NF)  < 5 '
```

Comment: а каким образом уже можно изменить права доступа к уже найденным файлам?

Comment: Вообще `chmod`. Или вы про то, чтоб применить эту команду ко всем файлам, которые показала `find`?

Comment: @EVG, вообще говоря, это уже отдельный вопрос, который стоит опубликовать отдельным сообщением. Но в вашем случае я бы дописал к команде `| xargs chmod права`.

Comment: `find /your_path k -type f -print| awk -F/ ' length($NF)  < 5 ' | xargs -I{} chmod -v 645 {}`

Comment: Благодарю,разобрался.

Answer (score 4):

Утилита find умеет в регулярные выражения, и можно обойтись без вызова сторонних программ.

```
find -regextype egrep -regex '.*/.{,5}'
```

Первые три символа в шаблоне нужны из-за того, что `-regex` применяется ко всему пути, а мы хотим найти файлы, анализируя лишь их имя безотносительно местоположения. Кроме того, мы задали ключ `-regextype`, чтобы упростить наше регулярное выражение.

Обратите внимание, в регулярке мы записали пятёрку, что означает нестрогое сравнение. То есть команда выше выведет имена файлов, в которых *не более* пяти символов. Чтобы обеспечить точное соответсвие условию в вопросе, нужно заменить 5 на 4. (Но это уже будет не так интересно).

Comment: `{,5}` означает "меньше либо равно". Чтобы `< 5` было, можно `{,4}` использовать. Можно ещё так: `find -regex '.*/.?.?.?.?'`

Comment: верно! дописал дополнение об этом, второй вариант мне кажется более сложным - в нем больше символов

Comment: Если вы длину команды считаете важным, то второй вариант как раз короче (обратите внимание, нет `-regextype`)

Comment: да... точно ._.

Answer (score 2):

Пример с grep:

```
find ~ -type f | grep -P '/.{5}$'
```

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731778/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment1111217_731778) вы были правы про дубликат. В следующий раз, пожалуйста, отмечайте сразу: тревога → закрыть → уже был задан → ссылка на нужный вопрос. Тогда вопрос попадет в очередь проверок. Если действительно дубликат — проверки в очереди это подтвердять. И не бойтесь ошибиться с предположением, там ещё пять человек проверят отметку.