# Распределенное программирование

Tags: многопоточность

Я совершенно запутался в видах высоконагружаемых систем. А именно: многопоточные, асинхронные, многопроцессные, неблокирующие и синхронные типы программ.

Пожалуйста, опишите кратко каждый из этих типов.

Comment: возможно, дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/

Comment: Нет, мой вопрос затрагивает не только асинхронное и пногопоточное программироывания. Но благодарю Вас.

Comment: Изменил вообще, на "распределенное программирование".

Comment: Шутки шутками, но на такой вопрос сложно ответить нормально. Это очень сложная область, по которой написаны куча книг. Вот если бы был конкретный вопрос по какой-то небольшой части, то ещё ладно, но в такой формулировке вопрос слишком обширен.

Comment: Как вариант, можете создать [общий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) и понемногу добавлять информацию.

Comment: На самом деле, это точный дубликат. Поскольку многопроцессное = многопоточное, асинхронное = неблокирующее. После дедупликации терминов ответ на тот вопрос отвечает и на этот, и даже больше.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов эти термины объяснены в ответах на вопрос [Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-vs-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Пожалуйста, прочитайте их.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов `мой вопрос не является дубликатом, вероятно к сожалению` — почему вы сделали такой вывод?

Comment: Потому что, здесь мне ответа не дали, скорее всего из за не компетентно заданого вопроса.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов так вот же ответ, здесь: [Многопоточное vs асинхронное программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445768/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-vs-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)